# Excluding weekends or non-business hours from difftime in R

Tags: r, datetime

The dataframe below contains timestamps related to when an incident is logged and resolved. Vector `ResolutionDiff` contains the difference in minutes fromthe Resolved and Logged vectors as calculated by the following statement:

`dataset$ResolutionDiff <- difftime(dataset$Resolved, dataset$Logged)`

```
| Reportnumber | Priority | Logged          | Resolved        | ResolutionDiff     | netdifftime |
|--------------|----------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------|-------------|
| 1            | High     | 22/1/2016 17:52 | 25/1/2016 13:35 | 406288333333333,00 |             |
| 2            | Medium   | 18/1/2016 13:09 | 22/1/2016 12:55 | 5745.7             |             |
| 3            | Medium   | 15/1/2016 10:47 | 18/1/2016 13:06 | 445876666666667,00 |             |
| 4            | Medium   | 15/1/2016 10:32 | 18/1/2016 13:04 | 447173333333333,00 |             |
| 5            | High     | 14/1/2016 14:13 | 14/1/2016 15:33 | 792333333333333,00 |             |
```

I am trying to calculate the vector `netdifftime` by conditionally subtracting non-working hours from ResolutionDiff, such as weekends, when `dataset$Priority !=High`. For example, for row 1, the expected output in netdifftime would be 4062.883 - (48*60) = 1183.

Is there a way to do such a task in R? I have been digging into libraries like lubridate and suspect that a possible solution would be to create a temporary variable with weekend intervals which could then be checked against the corresponding interval for dataset$Resolved, dataset$Logged, but have not managed to get something to work.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this. You just need to thoroughly define your rules. ...Also, FYI- `dput` your example data vs (or in addition to) pasting it.

Comment: An approach that might be not memory efficient seems to be `dataset$ResolutionDiff - mapply(function(d1, d2) sum(as.POSIXlt(seq(d1, d2, "day"))$wday %in% c(0L, 6L)) * (24 * 60), dataset$Logged, dataset$Resolved)`. It might help to post a more complete example.

Comment: It will actually be a bit more complicated, as the net difference should also take into account whether the incident was logged during or outside business hours, similar to excel's `NETWORKDAYS` function. I'm currently working on an approach, so I;ll also update the original question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I ran in to the same question and ended up writing a function for that, and later build a package for it.
https://github.com/janzzon/difftimeOffice